# Find polynomial function through 30 points with polyfit

Tags: python, numpy

I need to find the polynomial function of degree 29 that exactly fits thirty data points. We can be sure, that such a function exists. However, the error of numpy.polyfit increases dramatically after only three points.

```
import numpy as np

y = [126,  34,  78, 120,  83,  62, 104,   6,  70, 142, 147,  63,  35, 126,   9,  84,   7, 122,  93,  29,  95, 141,  42, 102,  38,  96, 130,  83, 138, 148]

print(len(y))

x = np.arange(len(y))
f = np.polyfit(x,y,30)

def eval_polynom(f, x):
    res = 0
    for i in range(len(f)):
        res += f[i] * x**(len(f)-i-1)

    return res  

for i in range(len(y)):
    print(y[i], " -- ", eval_polynom(f, x[i]))
```

My data points are (x,y) with x = [0,1,2,3,4,...,29]

The output is

```
126  --  125.941598976
34  --  34.7366402172
78  --  73.703669116
120  --  134.514176467
83  --  51.6471546864
62  --  105.143046704
104  --  70.1470309453
6  --  13.808372367
70  --  347.425617622
142  --  -1281.11122538
...
```

Is there a way to get the exact polynomial function such that the error is 0?

Comment: Your data points are like (0,126), (1,34), (2,78), ... is that right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I'll add this information in my question.

Comment: Is there a reason you need a polynomial for this fit? Why not e.g. fourier coefficients.

Comment: No. It can be any function. I thought a polynomial was the easiest function.

Comment: Mathematically, polynomials are nice.  Numerically, they are troublesome.  High order polynomials (and 29 is high) are sensitive to numerical errors.  @JonasAdler asks the right question: why do you need a single polynomial to fit these values?  What are you going to do with it?  Maybe you should look into other methods of [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).

Answer (score 1):

y - green, polynome - red, error - blue, it's 140 degree polynome

[image: y - green, polynome - red, error - blue]

> I need to find the polynomial function of degree 29 that exactly fits thirty data points. We can be sure, that such a function exists

Why you sure of this? I tried some twists and visualizations and think you datapoints can't be fit by such polinome.

I'v tried Chebyshev's polynomes, it's doing better, but still can't fit these values even with 140 degree polynome.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from numpy.polynomial.chebyshev import chebfit,chebval
%matplotlib inline

y = [126,  34,  78, 120,  83,  62, 104,   6,  70, 142, 147,  63,  35, 126,   9,  84,   7, 122,  93,  29,  95, 141,  42, 102,  38,  96, 130,  83, 138, 148]

print(len(y))

x = np.arange(len(y))
c = chebfit(x, y, 30)

p = []
for i in np.arange(len(y)):
    p.append(chebval(i, c))

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': x, 'y': y, 'p': p})
df['diff'] = df['y'] - df['p']
sns.pointplot(x = 'x', y = 'y', data=df, color='green')
sns.pointplot(x = 'x', y = 'p', data=df, color='red')
sns.pointplot(x = 'x', y = 'diff', data=df, color='blue')
```

Answer (score 1):

There's almost certainly an integer overflow issue (due to large exponents) in your `eval_polynom` function, because the values in `x` are all integers. Try to replace

```
res += f[i] * x**(len(f)-i-1)
```

with

```
res += f[i] * float(x)**(len(f)-i-1)
```

You'll probably end up with values that still don't perfectly match, but remember that floating point operations are inherently inaccurate. Even more so if numbers become large, as is the case here.

Comment: Yep, that's the reason why the error becomes that large. Thanks for the hint. However, I am still looking for a polynom with error == 0.

Answer (score 1):

While not exact, you get much better results if you use NumPys `polyval`

```
import numpy as np

y = [126,  34,  78, 120,  83,  62, 104,   6,  70, 142, 147,  63,  35, 126,   9,  84,   7, 122,  93,  29,  95, 141,  42, 102,  38,  96, 130,  83, 138, 148]

x = np.arange(len(y))
f = np.polyfit(x ,y, 30)

for i in range(len(y)):
    print(y[i], " -- ", np.polyval(f, x[i]))
```

which gives

```
(126, ' -- ', 125.94427340268774)
(34, ' -- ', 34.674505165214924)
(78, ' -- ', 73.961360153890183)
(120, ' -- ', 133.96863767482208)
(83, ' -- ', 52.113307162099574)
(62, ' -- ', 105.65069882437891)
(104, ' -- ', 68.588480573695762)
(6, ' -- ', 14.814788499822299)
(70, ' -- ', 76.373263353880958)
(142, ' -- ', 149.39793233756134)
...
```

Note that you should be using a degree 29 polynomial to fit 30 points.

[image]

Comment: The error is still too large. Isn't there a way in numpy to compute the polynom that represents these values exactly?

Comment: Maybe I do not understand you correctly, but for a given set of n distinct data points, we can compute a polynomial of degree n-1. This polynomial is called Lagrange polynomial.

Comment: Edit: I was confused. Anyway, the point is that you cannot get it exactly. The main issue here is that the vandermonde matrix has condition number 46907455291793984.